# Nouislider slider not showing up in the webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, nouislider

Nouislider slider not showing up in the webpack project

Simply trying to add a slider and be able to just call it and do custom config for a situation, i don't see any errors popping up not sure what am i doing wrong. Slider class is in another .js file made only for it.

js script for the slider

**rangeSlider.js**

```
import * as noUiSlider from 'nouislider';
import 'nouislider/dist/nouislider.css';
export default class RangeSlider {

    constructor(selector = "[data-js-rangeSlider]", config = { start: [ 0, 100 ], range: { min: 0, max: 100 } }) {
        this.node = document.querySelector(selector);
        if(this.node) {
            this.slider = new noUiSlider.create(this.node, config);
        }
    }
}
```

webpack entry file
**index.js**

```
import RangeSlider from "./js/rangeSlider.js";
const rangeSL = new RangeSlider(document.getElementById("rangeSlider"),{ start: [ 0, 100 ], range: { min: 0, max: 100 } });
```

html file where everything called

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>
        Slider Test
    </h1>
    <div class="rangeSlider rangeSlider--isDark" data-js-rangeSlider>
        <div class="rangeSlider__inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you added the script reference in your `html` file? also, you could show which webpack configuration you are using

Comment: Your class `RangeSlider` takes a string argument, a selector. Your `index.js` gives it a `Node`.